# Apply JQuery Rule to Subpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this sharepoint site collection, there is a home(main) page and subpages all of which retain a page layout. I use the standard `$(document).ready()` function to apply certain styles after the page is loaded. However, static locations for images are not applying correctly to subpages, and using relative locations doesn't work for the main page. How do I apply certain jQuery scripts to just the subpages and not the main page?

An example address would be

//somepage/SitePages/Home.aspx is being modified by using `$(document).ready()`

and how would I be able to execute a script on a page like

//somepage/subpage/SitePages/Home.aspx

by using(something similar to)

`$(document == '../subpages/SitePages/Home.aspx').ready()`

I'm ultimately trying to implement a script in jquery that would modify any subsite's homepage without changing the root's homepage.

Comment: subpages are loaded by ajax into main page? Use ajax callbacks to manipulate new content if that is the case

Comment: @charlietfl is this an answer?

Comment: asking for clarification about how sub pages work. If it is an ajax issue then yes this would be an answer

Comment: @charlietfl I realize i didn't ask a question properly, the post has been updated.

Comment: can parse the url...or simplest as far as efficiency is put a class or id on body tag at server...is that possible?

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunately not, it's controlled by the site collection admin and I can really only apply changes on the client side. Closest thing I could do is to add a class in jquery after-the-fact, but that brings right back around to this same question.

Comment: ok...so need to parse the url or..if there are eleemnts in page that are unique to a page could reference from those. Not hard to parse url though. The `location` object has properties like `href`, `pathname` ..`search` etc. Just a matter of determining url structure to watch